# Twilio is sending the Message Fall Back URL text along with actual text

Tags: twilio

Initially I have been using the TwiML response to send response to my text messages. But since my requirement has changed and I need to send more than 10 messages in response to my text hence I am now using the Twilio API to send the message out. So to fix this now I am trying to send nothing as the TwiML response for my Text Messages and instead using the Twilio API to send the actual messages out. I also have a  TwiML bin URL attached to my short code as a Message Fall Back URL in case Twilio is not able to connect to my REST API URL. So now when a Text message is received by Twilio it connects to my REST API and the response is sent. But I am getting the response from the Message FallBack URL first and then the actual response for my text message via the Twilio API. Is there anyway to avoid this? I can remove the Message Fall back URL but then what would happen in the actual case when Twilio is not able to connect to my server?

This is how I have added the code:

```
 var twilioResponse = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
 ...... have code that uses Twilio API to send out more than 10 messages. 
 ...... Since the messages are going out via Twilio API hence returning NULL to the       TwiML response

 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, twilioResponse.Element);
```

More Updates:

As I mentioned earlier I'm using the REST API to send an SMS. When a Text request comes Twilio server calls my URL supplied to the REST call.

Sometimes my server is little slow in responding - in which case twilio gets the fallback URL message and passes on the text message.

How do I increase the timeout ? This timeout is the time the server responding with TWIML.

Please help - any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

My first suggestion would be to check your accounts [App Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor) to see if Twilio is logging any errors.  The Fallback URL should not be getting requested unless Twilio fails to get a valid response from the primary URL.

The default timeout for a Twilio request is 15 seconds, so if your server is taking longer than that to respond there may be a bigger issue happening with your server or network.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes Twilio is logging the Error: 11205 - HTTP connection failure error.

Comment: Can we send a blank response to the TwiML element? Or does it expect a Non Null element response? What we are doing is Sending an OK response with a Blank Response Element but then using the Twilio api to actually send the messages out since we have more than 10 test messages to send for a single incoming request.

Comment: A <Response /> element should be fine.  However, if you are getting 11205 errors back then Twilio was not able to reach your server.  https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/11205

Comment: But I do see the Twilio request coming to our server from the event log. Also my Rest Api is doing the process as well as I get the text message via the Twilio Api. It's just that after 2 messages i get the fallback URL message as well along with the actual message.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server or caching server that could be intercepting the request?  If not, then I think the next step would be to send an email over to help@twilio.com and let our support team have a look at your account and see if they can see whats going on.

Comment: Yes, we are behind a proxy. But my API is receiving the text to which I need to respond and it does respond but as an outgoing message since now I use Twilio API. And so I am sending a blank TwiML response element. My Api calls the Twilio API to send out all the 12 messages and then returns the blank response with an OK. Will this be an issue due to timing? Because I see the reply coming in from the fallback URL between my other messages and then the subsequent messages come in.